# User Control Width of UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

I have an `UITextView` that is a subview of an `UIView`. The frame of the `UIView` can never change.

I added a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and a `UIRotateGestureRecognizer` to the `UITextView` so that user could scale and rotate the `UITextView`. However, I realized that pinching to scale does not work very well right now, because it doesn't allow user to increase the width of the `UITextView` if necessary. For example, if user pinch to scale the `UITextView` to a smaller size, the width of the `UITextView` should increase with more input until the width reaches the trailing edge of the `UIView`. How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add the UITextField in a UIView, and make a border or a triangle at the Bottom right corner of the UIView. The you can add a GestureRecognizer on the triangle, when you pan the triangle, the UIView's scale is changed, and then suit your UITextField for the UIView(Father View)